# Ignoring output not suppressed by /noconlog switch on msbuild

Tags: powershell, msbuild

Until recently, if I called `msbuild /noconlog /nologo mysolution.sln`, I'd get zero output when running in powershell. Now it seems to be ignoring `/noconlog` (i.e. `/noconsolelogger`) and prints this message:

> Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

Is there a way I can disable this output? Adding `/m` seems to suppresses the output, but it really seems like `/noconlog` should suppress that and I shouldn't have to use `/m` as a work-around.

Is this a bug that should be reported? If so, where?

---

Some context on why this matters....

I have a function in a powershell script. I check the result returned from the function below to see if msbuild succeeded or not. It worked previously, but now the message outputed by `msbuild` is included in the return, causing my comparison to fail.

```
function buildSolution ($file) {
    $path = $file.FullName
    & $msbuild /nologo /noconlog $path
    return $?
}
```

Here's where I check the result of that function:

```
$solutionsToBuild = $solutionsToBuild | where { -not (buildSolution($_)) }
```

Perhaps I can redirect the output of msbuild so it doesn't end up in what I'm returning from the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the verbosity level to `quiet` using [`/verbosity:q`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) as an argument.

Usage:

```
msbuild $project /verbosity:q
```

Paired with `/nologo`, it shouldn't output anything. (It didn't in my case anyways.)